# How to check keydown on div that if a valid character was pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spreadsheet, keydown

I checked already that if this was asked by others. But, every question was regarding input or textarea only and there was no perfect answer for me. Please note that I want this to work on div keydown. I have set div tabindex already and I can get key codes in keydown event for that div.

I am creating a spreadsheet in javascript using jQuery. And, in spreadsheet user starts typing on any cell in any row in any column. Now, I want to detect if a valid character is pressed so that I show the editing textbox right away in the selected cell.

So, when I convert keyCode to character using String.fromCharCode, I get a character for everything even if it is shift key or ctrl key. So, this is not what I want. This will give me 2 characters for shift & lets say G.

I do not know how to check if only a valid character like a, h, 0, 7 etc. was pressed by the user so that I show him the editing cell right away like google sheets or microsoft excel does. Also, I could have done it checking >= 65 and so on. But, I want to make it work for every type of keyboard in every language.

I am sure that its a very difficult job to achieve this, but I wonder how Google and Microsoft do this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Show the code that you have tried. Also specify what you mean by “a valid character”.

Comment: Thank you guys but I solved this myself. I cannot post an answer until before 8 hours. So, I will post the solution tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm sure you're using the *contenteditable* attribute as well, right?

Comment: No. Why content editable is needed for Keystrokes? Just tab index can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this myself.

When `keydown` event happens for the div, I create an `input` box and append it to body and I attach `keyup` event to that input box.
In `keyup` event, I can easily find that if something is typed or not.
If something is typed, then user wants to edit the cell otherwise I can check for special keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> and so on.

Please note that input looks annoying as it comes up as soon as user starts typing. So, I make it somewhere at `-1000px` with `position:absolute`. I also tried making input box `width` and `height` 0, but then I could not read the `.val()` from the box. So, I used `position:absolute; left:-1000px` instead.

May be this helps someone in any other related things. So, here is the code.

```
$(spreadsheet).keydown(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == /*movement_keys*/) {
    //move between cells
} else {
    var input = $('<input type="text"  style="position:absolute; left: -1000px; top: 0px;"/>').appendTo('body');
    $(input).focus();
    $(input).keyup(function(e) {
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            setTimeout(function() { spreadsheet.editCell($(this).val()); }, 1);
        }

        $(this).remove();
        $(spreadsheet).focus();
    });
}
```

});

I had to wait for `1ms` using `setTimeout` function to make focus perfect, otherwise focus was not going on the cell editor.